# Android - Fragment Transaction Custom Animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

how i create custom FragmentTransaction animation like flow free,one touch drawing(when the transaction start ,  white flash will appear and then the target fragment).
please help guys . 
tnx :)